# C# winforms instantiating unknown (at design time) form at runtime (late binding?)

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, binding, interface

I have a need to instantiate an instance of a dll containing a form at runtime. Currently I have a long switch statement with 75+ cases and growing rapidly. As this has all developed we have also developed a List that contains all the info to dynamically call the form.

Sample case now

```
...
case "state"
  State state = new State();
  state.Parent = this.Parent;
  state.ScreenNameLong = "State ";
  state.ScreenTitle = "St11 - State";
  state.SetupForm();
  this.OpenForm(state, state.ScreenTitle);
  break;
...
```

All info needed is now contained in a list element called menuItem which is already selected. It has form ("State"),  ScreenNameLong, ScreenTitle etc.. All forms to be called have Parent objects and SetupForm() methods.

All dll's are referenced in "using" statements and in project references.
It seems I should somehow be able to do something similar to this, once:

```
Form formToLaunch = (menuItem.form);
formToLaunch.Parent = this.Parent;
formToLaunch.ScreenNameLong = menuItem.descr;
formToLaunch.ScreenTitle = menuItem.scrNumber + " " + formToLaunch.ScreenNameLong;
formToLaunch.SetupForm();
this.OpenForm(formToLaunch, formToLaunch.ScreenNameLong );
```

I have beat my head against the wall and not found a good solution to this. I have researched using Reflection and Interfaces and they don't seem to fit the bill, or I am just not getting it...

Comment: `All dll's are referenced in "using" statements` What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your forms will need to implement an interface defining the common members, for example:

```
interface IForm : IDisposable
{
    Form Parent { get; set; }
    string ScreenNameLong { get; set; }
    string ScreenTitle { get; set; }
    void SetupForm();
}
```

Here `IForm` inherits from `IDisposable` per dbc's comment below.

Get the Type from the typename (presumably in your `menuItem.form`).  You might need to play around with this:

```
var type = Type.GetType("form_namespace." + menuItem.form + ", form_assembly_name");
```

Instantiate the type, cast as your interface, and do whatever you want with it:

```
var formToLaunch = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IForm;
if (formToLaunch != null)
{
    formToLaunch.Parent = this.Parent;
    formToLaunch.ScreenNameLong = menuItem.descr;
    formToLaunch.ScreenTitle = menuItem.scrNumber + " " + formToLaunch.ScreenNameLong;
    formToLaunch.SetupForm();
    this.OpenForm(formToLaunch, formToLaunch.ScreenNameLong);
}
```

Comment: I'd make `IForm` inherit from `IDisposable` to so it can be easily put in a `using` statement.

Comment: Ditto dbc's comment. You can always cast the `IForm` instance to `IDisposable` for the purpose of a `using`, but including it in the interface declaration would simplify matters, making it more convenient to use.

Comment: @dbc Good idea, I will add that.

Comment: Awesome answer! I was dancing all around right answer and missing the last tidbit!